# Where can Cirrus Aircraft VisionJet Oleo Struts Material and Dimension Specifications be found?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-systems

I am looking to get hold of Cirrus Aircraft VisionJet Oleo Struts Material and Dimension Specifications. Can anyone point me to or share where I can obtain these details. So far, I have been able to get general specifications at the following link.
https://cirrusaircraft.com/aircraft/vision-jet

Thanks.
Vedanth

Answer (score 1):

You're after the landing gear oleo Source Control Drawings.  You need to contact Cirrus' [tech support](https://cirrusaircraft.com/service-support/) and request the drawings from their engineering organization via their support organization, who may or may not want to help you, or may charge for them if they do.

I expect they won't want to provide them because they'll suspect that it's for someone who wants to make a PMA (Parts Manufacturer Approval) copy. It's usually pretty tough to find source documentation like that for a product that is in current production.

Comment: Thanks. I really do not want the detailed info.. which I agree they may not provide. Would you be aware on details of the above mentioned aircraft or others of similar type.. Details such as length of 1) Oleo strut length, 2) Oleo stroke length, 3) Oleo diameter , 4) Oleo strut Operating temparature (min/max). I am not looking for accuratedetails. Even  general approximate information  should do.Thx.